# eCryptfs - is the wrapped password the only thing I need to decrypt encrypted files?

Tags: encryption, ecryptfs

I have a standard setup created by `ecryptfs-setup-private`. I've tried to figure out if the (unwrapped) wrapped passphrase [UWP] is the only thing I have to worry about (except the encrypted files themselves).

My understanding is that any key used by eCryptfs, fnek or fekek, is derived from the UWP by salting and hashing it. Does that mean there is some hardcoded salt somewhere in eCryptfs' code or that the UWP is not the only thing to remember if I want to decrypt my data on another computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I know the answer.

After I unmounted the private folder and removed the `~/.ecryptfs` folder I was able to recover the data using the `ecryptfs-recover-private` command. It asked only for the mount passphrase and then it was able to decrypt both the data and the filenames.

Now, to be 99,99% sure that there's no catch I also checked eCryptfs' source code.

[Ecryptfs-mount-private](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ecryptfs/ecryptfs/trunk/view/head:/src/utils/ecryptfs-mount-private) calls scripts like [this one](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ecryptfs/ecryptfs/trunk/view/head:/src/utils/ecryptfs_insert_wrapped_passphrase_into_keyring.c#L38) or [that one](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ecryptfs/ecryptfs/trunk/view/head:/src/utils/ecryptfs_unwrap_passphrase.c#L38) and they all share the following piece of code:

```
rc = ecryptfs_read_salt_hex_from_rc(salt_hex);
if (rc) {
    from_hex(salt, ECRYPTFS_DEFAULT_SALT_HEX, ECRYPTFS_SALT_SIZE);
} else
    from_hex(salt, salt_hex, ECRYPTFS_SALT_SIZE);
}
```

-- where [ecryptfs_read_salt_hex_from_rc()](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ecryptfs/ecryptfs/trunk/view/head:/src/libecryptfs/key_management.c#L669) calls [rcryptfs_parse_rc_file()](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ecryptfs/ecryptfs/trunk/view/head:/src/libecryptfs/cmd_ln_parser.c#L213) which in turn tries to read the salt from some `.ecryptfsrc` file.

And if that file doesn't exist or the read attempt is otherwise unsuccessful the default value of [ECRYPTFS_DEFAULT_SALT_HEX](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ecryptfs/ecryptfs/trunk/view/head:/src/include/ecryptfs.h#L75) is used. Btw in the subsequent line of the header file there is the ECRYPTFS_DEFAULT_SALT_FNEK_HEX constant which is used in the [ecryptfs_insert_wrapped_passphrase_into_keyring()](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ecryptfs/ecryptfs/trunk/view/head:/src/libecryptfs/key_management.c#L571) function as a hardcoded salt value.

Case closed?

EDIT: I found this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ecryptfs/+bug/376580/comments/3